# Shopify - Can not get the authorization code from the redirect URL

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have created a shopify partner account and also created an **APP** that app has the **client id** and **secret** key. Now, I need to implement the shopify **oauth** system. To do that I am preparing the URL like this:

```
$shop  = '489207-2'; // Some shop name
$client_id = 'my-client-id';
$scope = 'write_products,read_shipping';
$redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/practice/shopify/redirect.php';

$redirect_url  = "https://{$shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id={$client_id}&scope={$scope}&redirect_uri={$redirect_uri}&access_mode=per-user";
echo $redirect_url;
```

So above code is generating a link and after click on that link I redirect to ths page:

[image]

**Now why I can not click on the Install app button? Why it is disabled?**

## That was my code to test the oauth.

But I have tried another way which is from the **Test your app** section.

[image]

when I click on **Select store** its showing me this page:

[image]

Now, when I click on this **Tidy Shopping Deelopment** link it's redirect me to this link:

```
http://localhost:8888/practice/shopify/?hmac=c17c458f95d9237cbbfeff9acdcd99191e0c44eeed5d7424ec3cfe602942afaf&host=dGlkeS1zaG9wcGluZy1kZXZlbG9wbWVudC5teXNob3BpZnkuY29tL2FkbWlu&shop=tidy-shopping-development.myshopify.com&timestamp=1673514817
```

Here I can't see the authorization code, **why?**

Comment: One thing I can think if is that one of the requirements is that you need a valid SSL so http://localhost wouldn't really work, also I don't see how Shopify could communicate with your local computer

Comment: @SeanS. thank you. I think thats an issue. I need to test it on the live server.